# Как сделать нестандартную рамку вокруг кнпоки используя css?

Tags: css, css3

Нужно сделать рамку для кнопки используя CSS. Я по разному побывал, но ничего не получается.

Побывал сделать используя градиент https://codepen.io/Gildars/pen/YYjGVP

```
.btn {
  background: no-repeat center center,radial-gradient(closest-side, #fff 0, #fff 84%, rgba(50,46,46,0) 88%, rgba(50,46,46,0) 100%);
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: all 250ms;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  display:flex;
  font-size:18px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center

}
```

Вот что должно получится.

[image: Вот что должно получится.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для этого `border` и `box-shadow`:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
button {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 250ms;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff;
}
```

```html
<button>Войти</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
button {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 250ms;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;  
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #000, 0 0 0 6px #fff;
}
```

```html
<button>Войти</button>
```

Comment: А как сделать что бы рамка вокруг кнопки была не черная а прозрачная?

Comment: @Gildars https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/3rsdcnbo/

Answer (score 1):

Градиент убрать, и:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5px white;
```

Если кнопка квадратная есть еще  `outline`.